# How to get the content of an edit box of another process in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

### Question:

In my program, I want to get the content of a specific edit box (or input box, text box...) of another process. For example, when the cursor is in the first column, "TextBox1" should be returned.
[image]

### What I have tried

1. [Use GetDlgItem and GetWindowText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690333/get-text-from-an-edit-control)
2. Send `WM_GETTEXT` message to the window, which was suggested in [a Q&A in from the august 2001 issue of MSDN Magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2001/august/c-q-a-getting-the-text-of-a-window-in-another-application;-making-backspace-work-in-the-explorer-bar) and [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352236/reading-from-a-text-field-in-another-applications-window)

```cpp
char currentContext[256];
SendMessage(cfg.mainWnd, 
WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(currentContext) / sizeof(currentContext[0]), (LPARAM)currentContext);  
// cfg.mainWnd is the window which edit boxes lie in.
```

3. EnumChildWindows and callback

```cpp
HWND GetInputWindow()
{
    HWND activeWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    // lpdwProcessId cannot be null...
    DWORD a = 1;
    LPDWORD lpdwProcessId = &a;
    auto threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindow, lpdwProcessId);
    std::cout << "ThreadId: " << threadId << " ProcessId: " << *lpdwProcessId << "\n";
    return activeWindow;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Being called.\n";
    char temp1[256];
    char temp2[256];
    GetClassNameA(hWnd, temp1, 255);
    if (!strcmp(temp1, "Edit"))
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(temp2) / sizeof(char), (LPARAM)temp2);
        return false;
    }
    printf("text: %s", temp2);
    MessageBox(NULL, temp2, L"test", MB_OK);
    return true;
}
// ...
HWND activeWindow = GetInputWindow();
EnumChildWindows(activeWindow, EnumChildProc, 0);
```

All the methods above just get "MainWindow", i.e. the title of the window in the example above.

### Appendix

I used spy++ to monitor the window in the example. Just one window was catched.
[image]

Comment: Have you ran Spy++ to confirm that those textboxes have an associated HWND?  A lot of modern apps do a custom draw of all their controls (hence, no child HWND).

Comment: And just by looking at the screenshot provided, those fields do not look like standard Win32 EDIT controls.

Comment: And if not, you can probably switch to using the Windows Accessibility APIs to read that data, assuming the developers coded it to be accessible from screen readers.

Comment: @selbie. Thanks for your reply. I have used spy++. The window in the example doesn't have child HWND (you see it in the newly added appendix in my post). I will check the Windows Accessibility APIs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. The example is generated from .net framework

Comment: UIAutomation is the library you need

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).